# How could a teleporter scientifically be stopped from using their ability?

Tags: science-fiction, teleportation

#### Background:

Subject LN96TN04 is a teleporter. He was not born this way but made this way in a lab. He's kept in the laboratory and tests are run on him constantly to develop his abilities. Sometimes, LN96TN04 escapes.

Aside from putting him under or physically stopping him, what could be used to keep him from teleporting? Say the researchers put a failsafe inside of his body that integrated into his genetics and they activated this failsafe, what would that failsafe be?

#### Preferences for a solution:

- That it would be a material injected into his body
- It's switch-activated
- There's no way around it

#### SOME EXTRA ASKED FOR INFO:

- LN96TN04 is a human science experiment whose DNA is spliced with the genetics of an alien. These genetics are what give him his abilities.
- The laboratory he's held in is hi-tech and well-funded enough for vast preventative measures.
- His teleportation is mind's eye-based, meaning he needs to be able to visualize where he's going, with a general spatial awareness of the area he's going to, and a physical visual helps as well.
- His teleportation works a bit just like a wormhole, he disappears from one spot and rips through space to appear in another.

Comment: Without some indication of how his teleportation *works*, we have no hope of knowing how it could be prevented.

Comment: You should describe your "teleporter", it's really unclear right now : Is it a magic human? A robot? A jumbled up machine? Then, how does your teleporter work : Does it need energy? What does it do, physically speaking? How far can it teleport and is there a cooldown time between each teleport? Finally the prison and its guards : What is the tech level and money available to prevent escape? There are a lot more to be detailed, this is only a starting point ;).

Comment: Alfred Bester's *The Stars My Destination* (1956) explores this quite well. His teleporters require a clear knowledge of where they are, where they are going, confidence that the teleport will happen, and a moment of concentration. They can be prevented from teleporting by using darkness, mazes, confusion, concussions, and other means. The lesson is that how to prevent teleporting depends upon how your teleportation works...which you have not told us.

Comment: Some information on the teleporter: He's a human science experience with DNA spliced with the genetics of an alien, and these genetics are what give him his abilities. It's a little handwave-y right now. The lab he's in is hi-tech and well-funded enough for vast preventative measures. His teleportation is mind's eye-based which means he needs to be able to visualize where he's going with a general spatial awareness of the area he's going to.

Comment: Following your rules, you cannot stop him from teleporting to any place he already knows (like Grandma's house or that grocery store in Cleveland) without the use of disabling drugs or devices. You made teleporting too easy.

Answer (score 1):

**Lies.  Fear.  A little bit of hoax.**

The lab is safe.  But people there are afraid of what is outside.  The lab is the last refuge for the humans.  Demonic aliens roam the outer world.  Humans who are caught are eaten, and eaten slow.  Really the lab is the only safe place.  That is the story and everyone sticks to it.

The area immediately outside the lab is actually like this.  It is terrible.  There are some demonic alien type things there.

Beyond that it is just regular earth.

Your teleporter is afraid of what is outside the lab.  He does teleport around inside the lab in a puckish manner, swiping food, doing pranks etc.  He does not go outside the lab because when he checked what was right outside it matched what he has always been told and now he believes.  He is afraid of what is out there.

Answer (score 1):

Put a device inside him which causes pain when it cannot receive  a radio signal. This signal is, of course, weak enough to only be receivable in a narrow radius around the lab.

Answer (score 0):

## Disable the brain's grid cells, place cells, and head direction cells.

The brain has particular neurons which help you determine your location. It has grid cells in the entorhinal cortex, which tell you where you are relative to past locations, place cells in the hippocampus which map out new locations, and head direction neurons in the entorhinal cortex which help get a sense of direction wherever you point your head of think of doing so.

They have an on switch on all these cells. So long as he gets a chemical in the air, they stay on. If he leaves his compound all those brain regions spontaneously shut off. He loses any sense of direction or maps of places, making teleporting impossible, and generally making navigation extremely hard.